# Format an int with zero padding in Java

Tags: java, junit

How do I get the following assertion to succeed?

```
{
  int i = 5;
  assertEquals("005", String.format("%1??s", i));
}
```

Problem: I need to format an int as a string of equal length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
assertEquals("005", String.format("%03d", i));
```

Adding a leading zero to the width of the [format](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) says that you want the field left-padded with zeroes.

From the docs under 'Number Localization Algorithm', pt. 4.:

> If the '0' flag is given, then the
>   locale-specific zero digits are
>   inserted after the sign character, if
>   any, and before the first non-zero
>   digit, until the length of the string
>   is equal to the requested field width.